# grub-install on Separate Device Affects Existing Grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, mount

I have Ubuntu 20.04 as my host machine. I create an image that I intend to use as an image for `qemu` that will have just the linux kernel and my program:

```
sudo su
# Create 1G image
dd if=/dev/zero of=example.img bs=1M count=1024
# Create loopback device
losetup -Pf --show example.img
# Create esp and root partitions
cfdisk /dev/loop11
mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop11/{root_partition}
mkfs.fat -F12 /dev/loop11/{esp}
# Mount
mount /dev/loop11/{root_partition} example
mkdir -p example/boot/efi
mount /dev/loop11/{esp} example/boot/efi
# Install grub
grub-install /dev/loop11 --skip-fs-probe --boot-directory=/home/ryan/example/boot
```

This completes with no errors.
However, it seems that this has affected my local grub in `/boot`. Before this, when I booted my machine I was given the option to select Ubuntu or Windows, i.e. was presented with a grub menu. After this, I get no such option (even after altering BIOS boot order) and boot directly to Windows.

Why would this affect my local `grub` when I'm explicitly not touching it? Shouldn't it be isolated?

Is this the correct way of installing `grub` for my purposes? I feel like this is a relatively simple task, however I don't want to have to reinstall my host OS every time.

Comment: Ubuntu's version of grub only creates one "ubuntu" entry in UEFI. When I changed that entry for a second install, grub created new entry, but something in shimx64.efi or grubx64.efi is hard coded to use /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg. So only one grub.cfg works. You may want to try with a different grub. One install I tried, seemed to embed grub into grubx64.efi, so could not be edited, just updated. Have not tried just downloading grub and using it.

Comment: @oldfred I'm running `grub-install` on a loop back device not a physical storage device. Therefore when I `umount` it's just a series of bytes on my host machine's `ext4` partition. So shouldn't `/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` still be valid for my host machine's `grubx64.efi`? All I want is to install a bootloader to this loop back device without it affecting my host machine's bootloader.

Comment: Is GUID shown in UEFI the loopback device? `sudo efibootmgr -v` To see GUIDs aka partUUID: `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid`

Comment: @oldfred Thank you for those commands. I noticed that `grub-install` sets the original _ubuntu_ efi entry to point to the GUID of the loopback device ESP, hence why it was not rebooting correctly. As a work around I created a new efi entry and deleted the old one on my host machine, i.e. `efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -L OrigUbuntu -l /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` and `efibootmgr -Bb {boot_num_to_delete}`